# Why Does ActiveRecord Scope Modify Class Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple class defined as follows

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   
 scope :active, lambda {
   puts User.all.to_sql
   puts self.to_sql
   where(inactive: false)
 }
```

When I run this `User.where('id = ?',1).active`, then `puts User.all.to_sql` and `puts self.to_sql` both output the same sql.

> "SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (id = 1)"

> "SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (id = 1)"

I know I can use `User.unscoped.all` to remove the where clause, but why is the class level scope different in this context?

Comment: I don't get those results. I see `SELECT "users".* FROM "users"` and `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1` from the `puts` calls.

Comment: I'm on `ruby 2.5.9p229` and `Rails 5.2.8.1`.  Is this just a bug thats been fixed?  Can you share your version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mu is to short` helped me track this down.  This is a bug that was fixed in rails 6.1.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_1_release_notes.html

> Named scope chain does no longer leak scope to class-level querying methods.